# iOS and Android: Is There a Way to Install an App From a Kiosk?

Tags: android, ios

I very vaguely remember hearing about some technology awhile ago (maybe NFC?) that somehow made it possible for a user to install an app on a phone simply by bringing it close (or maybe tapping it?) to a sales kiosk with the appropriate hardware.  However, I'm having trouble finding any reference to this technology, and I'm starting to wonder if I dreamt it up.

Regardless, my question is this: I know you normally install apps through the iOS/Android app store, but for either ecosystem is there any alternative way (with the user's permission of course) to install an app from a nearby device such as another phone, blue tooth transmitter, etc.?

Comment: Today Apple does not allow app distribution outside AppSotre. With Android you can even transfer APKs, but is still "unofficial". I think NFC is just a handshake, and NFC make something like a QRCode, it will provide a URL to the AppStore/PlayStore.

Answer (score 0):

As Douglas Junior suggested in the comments, there is currently no way to install iPhone apps outside of the app store.

In the Android ecosystem there is a way, using Android Beam:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#p2p

However, this is probably a dead-end for most people, as there's no point in setting up a kiosk that only half your customers can use.